# How to set custom border radius and zIndex in react-navigation for screen in a drawer navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using react-navigation v 6.1 for drawer navigation, I am trying to implement the following:

[image]

Currently this is what I was able to achieve:

[image]

How can I set border radius for the stack or routes that has been navigated by the user?

I tried to set the `sceneContainerStyle` border radius on `screenOptions` for `<Drawer.Navigator>` but seems that there is actually another child view inside the scene view.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials I found a hack since I was using nested navigator it appeared that navigator had a child view which wraps the current screen view, first I set theme for:

```
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppGlobalNavigator from './navigation'

const navigatorTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  },
};


const App = () => )
 <NavigationContainer theme={navigatorTheme}>
    <AppGlobalNavigator/>
 </NavigationContainer
)
```

Then I got a transparent screen views, I wrapped each component with view which has `backgroundColor` set to white color as as set `borderRadius` before passing them to navigator screen `<Stack.Screen>`.

Result:

[image]